# How do estimation commands find variable names in formulas in R?

Tags: r, nls

I'd like to estimate a large number of models using R's `nls()` function on a user-defined function.  Since many variables are fixed across my specifications, I'd like a way of pre-setting them in my function, but I don't properly understand how R looks for variables in functions contained in a formula.

I've had a look at the section on metaprogramming in Hadley Wickham's advanced R book, but it hasn't enlightened me.  Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to acheive, using the `mtcars` dataset:

I have tried setting a default value for variables that are fixed across specificaitons:

```r
expo <- function(x, theta, weight = wt) {
  x*weight^theta
}
```

I have also tried just using the column name of the fixed variable as a variable inside the function

```r
expo <- function(x, theta) {
  x*wt^theta
}
```

Both these approaches work if I just want to calculate the function, say with

```r
attach(mtcars)
expo(qsec, 1)
detach()
```

But if I try using my `expo()` function in an estimation routine, for example

```r
nls(mpg ~ phi + expo(qsec, theta),
    data = mtcars,
    start = c('phi' = -2, 'theta' = 1))
```

It fails with the message `Error in expo(qsec, theta) : object 'wt' not found`.  One possibility, brought up in the comments, is to simply pass the dataset, `mtcars` in this case, to `expo()` as an argument.  But since I will only call `expo()` inside of a call to `nls()` where the dataset is already an argument, I would be happy if I could find a way to avoid this repetition.

My ultimate goal after defining or calling `expo()` appropriately is to be able to do something like this:

```r
depvars <- c('qsec', 'drat', 'dist')
lapply <- (depvars, function(x) {
    formula <- as.formula(paste0('mpg ~ phi + expo(', x, ', theta)'))
    nls(formula,
        data = mtcars,
        start = c('phi' = -2, 'theta' = 1))
}
```

Comment: You might need `eval` and the like since expo is a function.

Comment: So with something like `eval(mtcars$wt, envir = globalenv())` in the function definition?

Comment: I think it is to "`eval`uate"  `expo` since currently it is not evaluated. Perhaps add a data argument to `expo` such that the variables are grabbed from that data? Or use `m(g)et` and define where they should be grabbed?

Comment: Something rudimentary and not the best(harcoded): `expo <- function(x, theta, weight = wt,df) {
  variables<- mget(c(x,"wt"),
                     envir= as.environment(df))
  variables[[1]] * variables[[2]]^theta
}`

Comment: Using your first `expo` function, can't you just write something like `paste0('mpg ~ phi + expo(', x, ', theta, wt)')` inside `as.formula`?

Comment: @Alexis that would work, but in practice there is a large number of variables to be included, I wanted a way of defining `expo()` so that it is clear which variables I actually set in each call.  I could pass the variable names to the function as a list, but then I still need a way of refering to them inside `expo()` during the call the `nls()`.

Comment: @NelsonGon, that works, only passing the column name to the function, i.e. x is a charcter string, not a name.  I'm still welcoming more elegant solutions, and I would still be happy to learn where `nls()` starts searching for the variables in the formula it's given - in the execution environment of the call to `nls()`, or somewhere else?

Comment: What is x supposed to be?

Comment: I'm referring to the `x` in your code snippet.  I was otherwise thinking `x` would be the (unquoted) column name, like the other variables in a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky thing is that R's lexical scoping searches in *enclosing* environments,
which can be confusing during calls because the caller environments can each have enclosing environments and things get confusing pretty quickly.

I'll be using the `rlang` package to debug this scenario.

First, if you defined `expo` in the global environment,
then that will be its enclosing environment:

```
expo <- function(x, theta) {
  x*wt^theta
}

rlang::get_env(expo)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

So when you call it, R will first search for variables in the function's call
(not caller!)
environment,
and then in the enclosing environment (global environment here).

I don't know what `nls` does exactly,
but I would have assumed that it creates an environment from the `data` you provide and evaluates the formula there.
However, it seems the environment it creates only contains the variables it can explicitly see in the formula,
something I found with:

```
expo <- function(x, theta) {
  cat("caller: ")
  print(ls(rlang::caller_env()))
  cat("enclosing: ")
  print(ls(rlang::env_parent(rlang::current_env())))
}

nls(mpg ~ phi + expo(qsec, theta),
    data = mtcars,
    start = c('phi' = -2, 'theta' = 1))
# caller: [1] "mpg"   "phi"   "qsec"  "theta"
# enclosing: [1] "expo"    
# Error ...
```

As we can see, the *caller* environment of `expo` contains the variables we can identify in the formula,
and its *enclosing* environment only contains the definition of `expo`
(the global environment).
This unfortunately means that you can't even use something like `eval.parent` inside `expo`,
because that environment won't have all variables from `data`.

If you still want to work around it,
you could modify `expo`'s enclosing environment with your data before calling `nls`,
something like:

```
expo <- function(x, theta) {
  x*wt^theta
}

environment(expo) <- list2env(as.list(mtcars))

nls(mpg ~ phi + expo(qsec, theta),
    data = mtcars,
    start = c('phi' = -2, 'theta' = 1))
# Error ... number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
```

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted Alexis's answer, since it addresses my original question.  I nevertheless thought I would share the solution I adopted, in case anyone finds it useful.

As Alexis says, the solution needs to involve modifying the enclosing environment of `expo()`.  Rather than manually doing this each time (and perhaps changing it back to the original environment after each call to `expo()`), my approach combines the requirement that `expo()`'s environment contain the right variables with NelsonGon's suggestion that I feed the dataset as an argument at some point.  I do this by creating a function factory, `make_expo()`, that sets the required variables and returns `expo()`, so that the variables are automatically in `expo()`'s enclosing environment:

```r
make_expo <- function(df, vars = c('wt')) {
  wt <- df[[vars[1]]]
  function(x, theta) {
    x + wt^theta
  }
}

expo <- make_expo(mtcars)

nls(mpg ~ phi + expo(qsec, theta),
    data = mtcars,
    start = c('phi' = 1, theta = 1))
# Error ... number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
```

I think this has two advantages.  First, it's more robust, since you don't need to remember to set the environment of `expo()`, it's automatically set when `expo()` is defined.  Nevertheless `make_expo()` is flexible - I can set defaults, or feed in different datasets.  Second, it keeps the arguments `expo()` requires down to those that I actually expect to vary in different calls to `expo()`, improving comprehensibility

I was surprised to learn that formulas create an environment in which to look up names that only contains the variables explicitly named in the formula, and not also other variables in the dataset passed to `nls()`, but there you go.